# Do you know any good courses/tutorials/blogs?

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, widgets

I am learning more and more about Magento 2 yet I still feel like there is much to learn. I was wondering what good sources/methods of learning the following subjects are.

### Basics

Things like the information about the MVC architecture of Magento 2, Resources for finding classes to use in your modules (Which classes to use in what situation) or the workflow of making a webshop in Magento 2.

### Advanced

I find it difficult to find good KnockoutJS information compatible with Magento 2. Information about widgets and specifically their admin options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For basics, there are several resources/websites. But official magento devdocs are great resource to learn because they are updated and give best practices. Just reading is not enough, I'd recommend to implement whatever you learn on these site and when you get stuck somewhere, that's where you'll learn when you'll search for solutions. The best way to understand Magento 2 structure is to implement things by using any online tutorial. They all give implementation details as well. And for Knockout, this is [a nice small implementation in minicart](https://kiwicommerce.co.uk/blog/how-to-add-free-shipping-bar-in-top-mini-cart/) to help you understand and then you can search about it as well according to your requirement. One more thing, the Magento core files have almost every functionality you might need in your work, all you need is to understand it's implementation. So, give those core files your time and understand how they go along. They are very much helpful. Practice more and you'll see things smooth in your way. :)

Comment: Thank you for the good answer! I've also found a pretty good source for learning more about Magento 2.
https://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2/